# Return only the queried element and its parent from a nested document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Schema Structure

```
Artist Schema
albums:[Albums Schema]

Album Schema
songs:[Songs Schema]
```

Now, i want to search by a song id and return the song, its parent album and the artist detail. I don't want to return a song and album other than the one matched. So far i have only been able to restrict it to returning the queried album using the positional or elemMatch but it still returns all the songs . Does anyone know a way of restricting both the song and the album elements to one ?

Comment: Seems like you can't use $elemMatch projection for nested arrays. On a side note, what if an album has two artists. Isn't that an issue with this schema?

Comment: Yeah, thats what i found out as well. I got close with aggregation framework and redact, but its very messy. And no, for the sake of my application, one album can only belong to one artist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples below are using the `mongo` shell for convenience but should be
straightforward to translate.

Assuming you have a schema similar to:

```
db.artist.insert({
    name: '"Weird Al" Yankovic',
    albums: [
        {
            name: 'Dare to Be Stupid',
            year: 1995,
            songs: [
                { track: 'A1', name: 'Like a Surgeon' },
                { track: 'A2', name: 'Dare to Be Stupid' },
                { track: 'A3', name: 'I Want a New Duck' },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'Polka Party!',
            year: 1985,
            songs: [
                { track: 'A1', name: 'Living with a Hernia' },
                { track: 'A2', name: 'Dog Eat Dog' },
                { track: 'A3', name: 'Addicted to Spuds' },
            ],
        },
    ],
})
```

You can use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to get the expected results:

```
db.artist.aggregate(

    // First match to reduce the number of candidate documents
    { $match: {
        "albums.songs.name": "I Want a New Duck",
    }},

    // Unwind 'albums' & 'songs' arrays
    { $unwind: "$albums" },
    { $unwind: "$albums.songs" },

    // Limit to matching song & album
    { $match: {
        "albums.songs.name": "I Want a New Duck",
    }}
)
```

Example result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53defb826ed136423e50d082"),
    "name" : "\"Weird Al\" Yankovic",
    "albums" : {
        "name" : "Dare to Be Stupid",
        "year" : 1995,
        "songs" : {
            "track" : "A3",
            "name" : "I Want a New Duck"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh good lord, you are a genius. I think i am bald after all the hair pulling here man. I never knew you could use the $match twice. Using $match before  $unwind is critical because otherwise mongo can't make use of indexing. Superb. Thanks :

Comment: @KhalidBajwa Indeed, almost all of the aggregation pipeline operators (aside from `$geoNear` and `$out`) can be repeated :). An initial `$match` can take advantage of indexes as you mention and will also cut down unnecessary processing of documents that won't match later in the pipeline. FYI, the MongoDB manual has some more tips on [pipeline optimization](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) as well as some interesting examples of [Aggregation with the Zip Code Data Set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/).